# What is meant by "There Will Be Blood"?

Tags: title, there-will-be-blood

Finally got around to watching [*There Will Be Blood (2007)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0469494/) last night, and I'm somewhat confused by the title.  I've got some possible references, and I'm not really sure if any of them are viable:

1. A reference to the men who died in the various mines
2. A reference to all the people Dan Plainview killed
3. A reference to the "war" that he had with preacher Eli Sunday
4. A reference to his relationship with HW

Can anyone help me understand this?